# ImageIntervention & Laravel 9: file_put_contents ERROR Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, intervention, file-put-contents

I'm using Laravel 9 and Image Intervetion to resize uploaded images:

```
public static function resize($file, $fileName)
    {
        $path = self::route();
        foreach (self::size() as $key => $value) {
            $resizePath = self::route() . "{$value[0]}x{$value[1]}_" . $fileName;
            Image::make($file->getRealPath())
                ->resize($value[0], $value[1], function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save(storage_path($resizePath));
            $urlResizeImage[] = ["upf_path" => $resizePath, "upf_dimension" => "{$value[0]}x{$value[1]}"];
        }
        self::$urlResizeImage = $urlResizeImage;
    }
```

But the line `->save(storage_path($resizePath));` returns this error:

**Can't write image data to path**

So in the Image Facade of Intervention, there's a **`@file_put_contents`**:

```
public function save($path = null, $quality = null, $format = null)
    {
        $path = is_null($path) ? $this->basePath() : $path;
        // dd($path);

        if (is_null($path)) {
            throw new NotWritableException(
                "Can't write to undefined path."
            );
        }

        if ($format === null) {
            $format = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }

        $data = $this->encode($format, $quality);
        $saved = @file_put_contents($path, $data);

        if ($saved === false) {
            throw new NotWritableException(
                "Can't write image data to path ({$path})"
            );
        }

        // set new file info
        $this->setFileInfoFromPath($path);

        return $this;
    }
```

And I tried removing **`@`** from **`@file_put_contents`** to see what's going wrong here, but then I got this:

### **file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\project\storage\upload/1401/11/images/questions/107200x200_1671289517402.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

So it basically says that it can not find the `$path` and when I uncomment `dd($path)`, this is the output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\storage\upload/1401/11/images/questions/108200x200_1671289517402.jpg
```

So what's going wrong here?

How can I properly save the resized images into this directory?

Please I beg you to help me with this because it's been a week that I'm struggling with this error and got headache!

---

**UPDATE #1**:

Here is the `route()`:

```
public static function route()
    {
        return "upload/" . jdate()->format('Y') . "/" . jdate()->format('m') . "/" . self::$typeFile . "/" . strtolower(self::$catType)."s" . "/" . self::$objId;
    }
```

And I changed it to this:

```
public static function route()
    {
        return "upload".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.jdate()->format('Y').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.jdate()->format('m').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.self::$typeFile.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.strtolower(self::$catType)."s".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.self::$objId;
    }
```

But still the same error occurs :(

Comment: So looks like your `self::route()` might have slashes that are pointing the other way. You see your path from the `C:\` disk forward has `\` and after the storage folder it goes like `/` which seems to be coming from the URL. You should try switching those to the other way with a replace function. You can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant which is the correct slash for file paths.

Comment: @thefallen I tried with `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` and the same error appears. Please check my update...

Comment: Try dumping the full path again and if it still has any `/` then change them using the character `\` directly and post updates if the error changes.

Comment: @thefallen Again the path comes with both `/` and `\` and tried to change it manually but the same error occurs. I think the problem is somewhere else

Comment: This is a bit of an obvious question but, does this folder exist on your system `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\storage\upload\1401\11\images\questions\`?

Comment: @thefallen Yes it does, it actually save the original image but with resized ones, returns error!

Comment: @thefallen I even put `File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);` at the save method of Image Facade to make the directory if it not exists but then I get the error: **Command (SetFileInfoFromPath) is not available for driver (Gd).**